# How to set up a personalized JIRA dashboard related to an Apache project

Tags: jira

I contribute to an apache project and would like to follow

- JIRA tickets assigned to me
- my activities, including commenting on other JIRA's
- all JIRA tickets matching a certain filter (i.e. sub-module) for that project

The "dashboards" feature on ASF JIRA do not immediately make it apparent how to achieve these three goals.  Hints on how to streamline this configuration/setup would be appreciated.

Comment: You can switch from one dashboard to another selecting by selecting a tab at the left. Copying or creating a dashboard does not automatically select it, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard  I am concerned here with actually *creating* the dashboard(s) that display those three types of info  - as opposed to just the mechanics of switching among existing dashboards.